# Как встроить онлайн карты в JavaScript веб-приложение?

Tags: google-maps, javascript, yandex-maps-api

Как встроить онлайн карты в JavaScript веб-приложение?

Comment: @Вероника Линдоренко, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем вы видите проблему, как ее воспроизвести и т. д.

Comment: @Вероника Линдоренко, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

Возможно это поможет 
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial

Или вот самый простой пример

```
var map;
    function initialize() {
      var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 8,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644)
      };
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
          mapOptions);
    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```